# How to click on the angular based checkbox as per the HTML provided through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to click on a checkbox using selenium python. I tried

```
buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Exact')]"); buttons.click()
```

I keep getting 
"ElementNotVisibleException:"

```html
<button type="button" data-ng-class="{iconCheck: event.locationExactness.isExact, inputBox:!event.locationExactness.isExact}" class="link icon locationButton inputBox" data-sfs-callout-visible="relativeExactnesses.length > 1" data-sfs-callout="sfs_-sfsLocationExactness-1-place-callout" data-sfs-callout-focus="sfs_-sfsLocationExactness-1-exact" data-ng-click="updateIsExact(relativeExactnesses.length > 1 ? true : !event.locationExactness.isExact)" data-autoname="NameAPlace_msypn_LocationExactButton"><!--
                                                                       
     --><span class="locationLabel ng-binding">Exact</span><!-- 
 --></button>
     <<pseudo:before>></<pseudo:before>>
     
     <!--
                                                                           
         -->
         <span class="locationLabel ng-binding">Exact</span>
         
         <!-- 
     -->
```

Comment: Is it possible to give us url of the page ?

Comment: It seems to be that you have two span element with same text "Exact". Which one you are trying to click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are locating one element, but are giving it plural name `buttons`. I would use singular name `button`.

Second thing is even in your code snippet there is two `span` which contain `Exact`. You have to change your locator so, that only one element(which you want to interact with) will be selected via selector.

For example, if you want the first `Exact` in your code snippet, you can use this xPath:

```
//button[@data-sfs-callout = 'sfs_-sfsLocationExactness-1-place-callout']/span
```

***Note:*** as @RajKamal already mentioned, there can be multiple elements on the page with text `Exact`. You can check this in dev tools by pressing `F12`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the element with text as **Exact** is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to invoke `click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='link icon locationButton inputBox' and @data-autoname='NameAPlace_msypn_LocationExactButton']//span[@class='locationLabel ng-binding'][contains(.,'Exact')]"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```